# What do I need to modify for Cannot validate argument on parameter &amp;amp;amp;#39;ServerName&amp;amp;amp;#39;?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm new to Azure SQL database(no prior experience with databases) and currently trying to get a degree from microsoft learn. I'm stuck at this lesson and can't seem to figure it out, tho i assume it's something easy. Problem:

```
PS /home/stefanhtml> $server = Get-AzSqlServer -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup
PS /home/stefanhtml> $logical_server = $server.ServerName
PS /home/stefanhtml> $databaseName = Get-AzSqlDatabase `
```

> > ```
> >                 -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
> >                 -ServerName $logical_server `
> >                 | Where DatabaseName -like Adventure*
> > ```

Get-AzSqlDatabase:
Line |
3 |                      -ServerName $logical_server `
|                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ServerName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

This is in Azure Cloud Shell from microsoft learn. Any reply would be much apreciated.

Comment: Did you set value to the `$resourceGroup`? It seems that the cmd can not get infos return to the `$logical_server `.

Comment: I just copyed the the text from the exercise and pasted it into the cmd without any modification (as requested in the exercise). How can I set the value to the $resourceGroup  ?   something like this DECLARE @resourceGroup VARCHAR(50) = 'logical_server' ? I`m pretty dumb regarding this problem. thank you for answering

Comment: Hi@iancu dorian. Since it was a common error. I've submitted an issue to MS . If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in the Exercise Sandbox. But in portal Cloud shell, I run these commands successfully. It seems to be a common issues. I've submitted an feedback to MS [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/support/troubleshooting?uid=learn.azure-sql-deploy-configure.6-exercise-configure-database&documentId=66c87595-6ba3-636e-45f1-db3ac16b520b&versionIndependentDocumentId=5a2a4c8b-b9d9-9dd5-167c-2fa4cc0ac3a9&contentPath=%2FMicrosoftDocs%2Flearn-pr%2Fblob%2Flive%2Flearn-pr%2Fazure%2Fazure-sql-deploy-configure%2F6-exercise-configure-database.yml&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flearn%2Fmodules%2Fazure-sql-deploy-configure%2F6-exercise-configure-database&author=antho#report-feedback) now. I think we will get news from Microsoft in time.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same error in the Exercise Sandbox and Azure Portal. For me it was due to restarting the project on unit 6 of 9. To run the code it required deploying the SQL database that was created in unit 3 in the same session as unit 6.

Effectively the code was trying to fine a SQL DB that didn't exist.